# Creating A database with 2 tables ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

Hello i am developing a database dbmain with 2 tables 
my code

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


// docsDir=[dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbDare.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];


if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO)
{
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblUser(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, StrName TEXT,Strusername  TEXT)";
        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {



            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to create table"
                                                            message:@"Failed to create table"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            //status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }



            char *errMsg1;
            const char *sql_stmt1 =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblVanish (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, strfilepath TEXT,datesaved  TEXT)";
            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt1, NULL, NULL, &errMsg1) != SQLITE_OK)
            {

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to create table"
                                                                message:@"Failed to create table"
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
                //status.text = @"Failed to create table";
            }
            sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    } else {
        // status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed to create open/create database"
                                                        message:@"Failed to create open/create database"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

}
```

after adding records to the table  i can see the rows  using lita software 
but when retriving the rows  via this code

```
 const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];
int iVal=0;
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT Strusername FROM tblUser";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

               strname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@" ,[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]];
            }



        } else {

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

i am not able to fetch any thing as there is no row displayed inside the table using ios but i can see the rows inside the table using lita  please suggest where i am getting this wrong

Comment: I would recommend to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a really nice wrapper for sqlite. A good [tutorial](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you copying the database file to document directory ?

And this condition looks very strange to me:

```
if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO)
```

If the database is not existing there, why don't you copy it to document directory?

Also you are creating table inside that if condition, means you are trying to create table on a non-existing db file.

Possibly you want to copy the `db` file first, then you need to create the tables.

**Or**

You need to change the condition like:

```
if([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]== YES)
```

Comment: Yes the db is stored in documents directory

Comment: @Rahul: are you sure the db is there ? If yes, then it won't work (because your if condition is wrong, please check my answer)

Comment: My db is in documents directory i had checked it's been created under /Users/Rahul/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/AA3FE47D-A062-4631-9E0A/Documents/ path

Comment: and i did checked the tables they are been formated under dbfile  but i am not able to retrive them

Comment: @Rahul: put a breakpoint or NSLog inside the if condition and check whether it is executing or not. Surely it won't execute if execute check the db open fails or not (it'll fail). Please check

Comment: I tried that you know the worst thing in this code is when i am creating 1 table it is working like wonders but if  i am creating 2 tables at the same time i am getting no values

Comment: @Rahul: if you are correct then I'm wondering. Because, 1) How this `[filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO` condition is true (as you said the db is there) 2) How the `sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK` work for the above condition. Both are opposite

Comment: @Rahul: Also `NSLog` the `databasePath` and check whether it is correct or not.